# is there and SPY++ for viewing .NET Framework messages only?

Tags: .net, message, trace

is there any good program for viewing functions / messages that are being executed on the .net framework in the background? i'm looking for something similar to what spy++ is doing, just for .NET only.

I have some weird behavior that i need to understand what causing it, and i don't think on any better alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/objectspy.aspx) at CodeProject, in the article there is a link to a Managed Window Spy (wfspy).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the same, but you could try Red Gate's [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm).